# What does AP stand for in llvm::APFloat and llvm::APInt?

Tags: llvm-c++-api

https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1APFloat.html
https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1APInt.html

I'd appreciate if you could answer the question.

Comment: See tag definition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apfloat  Please put more effort into researching before asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AP in APFloat stands for Arbitrary Precision, which means it can be used for calculations with very large precision. See also [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) on Wikipedia.